# jquery loop through json doesn't work as expected

Tags: json, ajax, loops, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a very simple ajax snippet that serializez a flask form (wtforms) and send it to an endpoint. the endpoint validates the form (wtforms validation). for now, all I need is a valid message if the form validates and a list of errors if it doesn't. this is my code:

```
@bp_catalogue.route('/catalogue/add_dataset', methods = ['POST'])
@login_required
def add_dataset():
    form = add_dataset_form()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return jsonify(success = 'ok!')

    return jsonify(error = form.errors)
```

This code works as expected and if all is ok, the 'ok!' string is available to me in jquery using response.success to be used as I wish. if the form doesn't validate, I expect it to send the errors back in a similar format, and it does. this is what a response looks like:

[image]

response.error contains several errors, such as a simple message saying that the empty inputs require a value. I'm looking to loop through these values and pass them on to a container under each form in my html. this is my code:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        data : $('form').serialize(),
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/catalogue/add_dataset'
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (response.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
            $('form')[0].reset();
            $('.response').empty().html(response.success);
        }
        $(response.error).each(function(key, value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

the issue is that my code to loop through the errors doesn't return what I expect it to. looking at the image, response.error is the object, with 2 elements: dataset_name and dataset_description. as I'm looping through those, I'm expecting the console to log the actual error message for each of the errors and it's not.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dataset_description` and `dataset_name` has value as `arrays` so you need iterate through that array to get required values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var response = {
  "error": {
    "dataset_description": ["something1", "something12"],
    "dataset_name": ["something02", "something13"]

  }

}

//loop through error 
$.each(response.error, function(key, value) {
  console.log(key + " : ") //key 
  //loop through value
  $.each(value, function(index, values) {
    console.log(values); //print value at that key
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thank you. I guess if my errors would only be a list of keys and values, my code would've worked, right? thank you!